# Why the prometheus counter isn't always bigger that the previous sample?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-net

I have setup prometheus-net in my ASP.net project and I have a counter for a job that processes products.

This is the Histogram counter but I have noticed the same thing in simple counters
[image]

The count isn't always bigger that the previous and this mess up with my graphs. It should be fine to reset to 0 but this is up and down.

I am wondering if this is a problem because I host the site at Azure Websites and I have two instances. Is it possible I have two counters, one running in different instance and when Prometheus gathers the metrics, it gathers them from two different sources?

Is there a way for the prometheus-net to use the redis so the metric is synched between two instances?

Comment: Prometheus on itself doesn't "messing with the sequence of the data". Most likely based on your description that Prometheus' scrape requests are in fact balanced between two instances. In case of multiple instances being present it's recommended to scrape them independently (not through balancer, but directly) and then aggregate raw data using promql (if needed).

Comment: Size of resources allocated to Prometheus doesn't really matter here: in worst case you might see some delay in responses, but nothing like results out of order. It seems a bit low, but it might be perfectly sufficient for small number of targets and metrics.

Comment: @markalex Yes, you are right, it must be because I have two instances. I see that from the data that are like two different sequences. I will add a label with the instance name, that way I can distinguish them

Comment: This is definitely a workaround. But I advise you once more, to scrape metrics directly from instances, not through a loadbalancer. This way you'll have away to know if one of instances is down, plus you wouldn't have issues with "continuity" of metrics, if they are missing for 5 minutes due to balancer behavior.

Comment: @markalex I will try to do that, but it seems that prometheus doesn't support sending cookies to their scraping request. So i have to figure a way to do that only with a URL